# Global config in titanium mobile mobile app

Tags: mobile, titanium

I am new to titanium mobile and I am a bit stuck. I have an app.js file and services.js file which sends some HTTP requests to an URI my issue is I want to create a global variable within the app.js which the services.js can use and other files as and when they get included.

What is the best way to do this ?

In PHP you would have a config file but how do you do in titanium mobile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using services.js from a Ti.include, it will have access to everything declared in app.js.  You usually create your own namespace and put 'global' variables in that:

```
var myapp = {};
myapp.myGlobalVariable = 'something';
```

[Here is a more complete example from Aaron Saunders](http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/6519148138/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-global-variables-scopes).

Answer (score 1):

You could do it 3 ways, depending on how long you'll need the variable. If it is needed outside of the session scope (so later on) you could store it either in an [Property](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.App.Properties-module) or [SQLite Database](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Database-module)

The last option, which is a session-only option is a regular JavaScript variable. Like Jeff has pointed out (copying his code here)

```
var myapp = {};
myapp.myGlobalVariable = 'something';
```

Declaring this `myapp` should be done before any function opens. So in the global scope.